# Code in handelling SpriteKit collisions dont work properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am using Spritekit which basically have some balls colliding, but I need to implement a method where if the ball is one side of the screen, it is of type "A" and if it is towards the right side of the screen it is type "B". For the only difference between type A and type B is their colour and their bit masks. To implement this, I have a rectangular physics body with the category bit mask set to the balls contact bit mask. However, not all the balls undergo the change from type A to type B and vice versa I can not figure out why. What I mean by this is, while there should be only type A balls on the left (Purple) and type B balls on the right (Green). Occasionally, there would be times where there are Purple balls on the left and Green balls on the right

Here is the code for the balls

```
func createOtherDots() {
         
        let dot = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 6)
        dot.fillColor = .purple
        dot.position = CGPoint(x: positionwithin(min: screen.width / 16, max: frame.midX), y: positionwithin(min: screen.height / 32, max: frame.midY))
        
        dot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 6)
        dot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.typeA 
        dot.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Bitmasks.midline
        dot.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =  Bitmasks.typeB + Bitmasks.typeA
        dot.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        dot.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        dot.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
        dot.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
        dot.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
        
        addChild(dot)
        allDots.append(dot)
    }
```

This would be called several times in a loop

for my border at the middle,

```
let midBoundry = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 0.0001, height: (screen.height / 32 * 30 + 3)))
        midBoundry.alpha = 0
        midBoundry1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - 2, y: frame.midY)
        midBoundry.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width: 5, height: screen.height))
        midBoundry.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        midBoundry.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.midline
```

And finally the collision,

```
public func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if let dot = contact.bodyA.node as? SKShapeNode{
            if dot.position.x > frame.midX{
                dot.alpha = 1
                dot.fillColor = .green
                dot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.typeB
            }else if dot.position.x < frame.midX{
                dot.alpha = 1
                dot.fillColor = .purple
                dot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.typeA 
            }else{
                fatalError()
            }
        } else if let dot = contact.bodyB.node as? SKShapeNode{
                if dot.position.x > frame.midX{
                    dot.alpha = 1
                    dot.fillColor = .green
                    dot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.typeB
                }else if dot.position.x < frame.midX{
                    dot.alpha = 1
                    dot.fillColor = .purple
                    dot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Bitmasks.typeA
                }
        }
    }
```

I tried several things, and this is what I finally came up with, It seems to have the most success, but many parts of my program is random, so there could be a simper, better solution. I originally used `didBegin` and thought it happened because the balls collided with one another while it was still in contact with the 'midline' so I used made the midline thiner and used `didEnd` instead. Did not work (which is why I am posting this question)

I'm sorry if this seems trivial, but im new to swift and especially spriteKit

EDIT: After playing around with this further, I changed the code such that upon creation, the balls would be pink, and after contact with the midline would it turn to Green and/or purple, and I discovered that now all that happens is that the balls are pink in B and A. Earlier, the pink balls would be green, so any non-contacted balls in A would not be noticed, but balls in B would seem out of place. I think this is because the balls are made before the midline. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a print("touched") statement inside your didEnd function to figure out how many times a specific node makes contact when moving trough the midline.

Comment: @StefanOvomate Thank you for trying to respond! I tried your suggestion and then came up with some results. Check the update please.